# Handling escape characters in Python 3 input function?

Tags: python-3.x, list, escaping, user-input, export-to-csv

I'm trying to run a program that will take input of card game cards, append them to a list, and then export the file as both a .txt file and also a .csv file. The program works, however it is unable to handle cards with a comma in the name.

For example, this function:

```
def card_adder(list):
    next_one = str(input("ADD: "))
    copies = input("How many? ")

    for i in range(int(copies)):
        list.append(next_one)
```

Will look like:

> ADD: Arboreal Grazer
> How many? 4
> There are currently 4 cards in the deck.
> ADD: Azusa, Lost but Seeking
> How many? 1
> There are currently 5 cards in the deck.

When the program gets to the designated number of main and sideboard cards (75 total), it will run the exporter function:

```
def exporter():
    ...
    deckname = input("Deck name: ")
    deck = open(f"{deckname}.txt, "w")
    for card in seventyfive:
        deck.write(card+"\n")
    deck.close()

    read_file = pd.read_csv (fr'C:\\Users\\[User]\\{deckname}.txt' error_bad_lines=False
    read_file.to_csv (fr'C:\\Users\\[User]\\{deckname}.csv', index=None)
```

However, this produces the following error in the terminal:

> b'Skipping line 5: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 29: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 30: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 48: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 58: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 59: expected 1 fields, saw 2\n'

Each line that it skips above is a card name that was input that contains a comma in the name. It will succesfully export the file, but skips each card with a comma in the name and saves an incomplete decklist.

Any suggestions on how to fix this to allow the user to input card names that contain a comma? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Previously posted solution was actually mistaken, however I identified that the issue was the default use of the comma as a separator in the pd.read_csv and read_file.to_csv lines. I changed the separator to "|", which never appears in these card names, and the program now accepts user input containing commas no problem.